Lightoff to speak about an engine start
Why the term lightoff (or light-off) is used to describe the moment an engine ignite/is started ?
I'm wondering why the suffix 'off' is used in an 'ON' sense (start, ignition) ?
Is there a etymologycal reason, an origin for this use ?
I found this word specifically in aeronautical applications. Could it be found elsewhere ?
e.g in an aircraft engine start procedure :
''verify indications below : Lightoff occurs within 20 seconds as indicated by a sharp rise in temperature''

There is an Aviation SE with lots of very knowledgeable people. This expression doesn't seem to have made it into the wider English language. As for etymology compare takeoff, blast off, kick off, start off, move off, lift off...

It's not a suffix, and it isn't used in the sense of the opposite of on. Off here is a particle. It is semantically weightless. All it does is form part of an identifiable phrasal verb that means whatever it means.

In your examples I understand the 'off' sense as something 'going away' from the ground, the center (take off, lift off, blast off...) or am I misunderstanding the meaning ? Sorry what is an Aviation SE ?

@Vincent SE = StackExchange - e.g. this is the ELU SE (English Language & Usage StackExchange). In the list of StackExchange sites, you'll also find one called "Aviation".

@StuartF I've asked the same question on SE Aviation, here are them answers link
